# How to get content of an image from a pattern?

Tags: c#, image-processing, imagemagick, emgucv, mask

I need to get the shape of the person given a pattern that came from the absolute difference of the two pictures, then converting it to bitmap to remove all the black pixels. How can I get the person's original body given these images

Original image, Absolute difference image, Removed black pixel(Bitmap)

[image: Original image]     [image: Absolute difference output] [image: Bitmap]

Comment: It's very unclear, to me at least, what you are asking. How did you generate a difference image from only a single starting image? What do you mean by *"converting it to bitmap to remove all the black pixels"*. It is already bitmap surely? What result is it that you want? I can already see the shape of the body in the second and third image?

Comment: Basically, I need to remove the background. Yes, the shape of the body is in the second and third image but not it's original color. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: So change all pixels that are not black (i.e the blue and cyan ones) in the second image into white, and then use the resulting image as the transparency of the first image? That will leave just the person in colour, on transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear to me what you are trying to do, but whatever it is, I think it is a 2-step process that will go something like this...

First, make a mask image that is black and white. Make it white where you want the original image to show through and black where you don't. Not sure which image you want to start from, but let's take the second one with black, white, cyan and blue in it. Let's make it pure black and white. You may choose a different method but I will just threshold:

```
convert 2.jpg -threshold 50% mask.png
```

[image]

Now, second step. Apply the mask as the opacity/alpha channel for the first, colour, original image:

```
convert 1.jpg mask.png -compose copy-opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

As the face of the lady is missing, there is some issue with the way you are generating the mask. I guess the face is too similar to the background in tonality. Consider having a look at **Morphology** to *"close the holes"*, along these lines:

```
convert 2.jpg -threshold 50% mask.png
convert outline.png -morphology Close Disk:12 mask.png
convert 1.jpg mask.png -compose copy-opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: I want to start from the 2nd image, but there's another problem in there. The face of the woman is not included when I get the absolute difference of the 1st image and the background, and applying threshold. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that the face is missing results from however you calculated the difference image since it is already black in there.

Comment: I don't know - I don't know how you made the difference image - you didn't show what you differenced the first image with, or how.

Comment: The difference of the images came from the AbsDiff function of EmguCV, by subtracting the 1st image to a background image

Comment: Ok, but I can't see the background image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104220/discussion-between-untitled-and-mark-setchell).